# ReactJs: Rendering on state change getting into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

Here I am trying to pass data between sibling components A and B, where I want to re-render component B upon completion of an asynchronous event in component A.

```
    class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                valueKey: '',
            };
        }
    
        parentFunction(dataFromChild) {
            this.setState({ valueKey: dataFromChild });
        }
        render() {
            const { valueKey } = this.state;
            
            return (
                <div>
                    <componentA
                      url={url}
                      ...
                      functionCallFromParent={() => this.parentFunction()}
                    />
                    <componentB valueFromParent={valueKey} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

class componentA extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: null,
        };
        // asynchronous request made to server which updates the state when response received.
        this._getTiles();
    }

render() {
        const { items } = this.state;
        

        if (items && items.asArray().length > 0) {
            functionCallFromParent('Hello From Child1');
            return (
                <div>
                    {tiles}
                </div>
            );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Issue is, every time componentA calls functionCallFromParent() ParentComponent's render is executed, and it re-renders componentA and componentB and this loop continues. Whereas, I want only componentB to be re-rendered when componentA ask it to.

Comment: You should call the `functionCallFromParent` inside the async code part (presumably `_getTiles`), rather than in the render function

Comment: @maya_nk99 but I don't have a button click or any user event.. Component B needs to re-rendered on completion of an asynchronous event that happens in componentA

Comment: if asArray() a function in Javascript ? I think it is in Python

Comment: Each time when you set the state, it will cause re-render of components which is using that state. So it is causing infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`functionCallFromParent()` is put inside `render()` in `ComponentA` which means it will get called every time the component is rendered/re-rendered which happens quite a lot! When that happens, the `ParentComponent.parentFunction()` will be called to set its own state which in turn causes a re-render to itself and its own children and this is how the loop is created. You should move this to the part of the code where you receive the response.